# Can anyone identify this European uniform? Likely Belgian or French

Tags: military, identification, uniform

## Does anyone recognise the uniform in this photo?

[image: unknown uniform]

I found it in a box of my late Grandma's photos and letters. She was Belgian, and I know some of our ancestors were in the French military thanks to a physical copy of our family tree.

Unfortunately there's nothing on the back other than what appears to be a very lightly pencilled capital letter H in the bottom right hand corner. My mum has no idea who it could be and I'm struggling to find any information on the internet, I think it could possibly be Belgian 1880-90s? Any insight would be appreciated! :)

edit:

Here are some helpful links and images I've found on the internet, I think it's most likely an 1880-90s uniform for the Belgian Army, possibly a guide, lancier or chasseur a cheval.

[Uniforms of the Belgian Army 1880-90 by Luca Stefano Cristini](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Uniforms_of_the_Belgian_Army_1880_90/qOvADqWYNYsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover)

---

[eBook: Uniforms of the Belgian Army 1880-90 Blogpost by Milgeek](https://molatero.blogspot.com/2013/10/ebook-uniforms-of-belgian-army-1880-90.html)

---

### Liebig S608 Belgian Military Uniforms

[image: Liebig S608 Belgian Military Uniforms, Liebig's Beef Extract "Military Uniforms" Italian issue, 1899 by Cigcardpix on Flickr]

Source: [Liebig S608 Belgian Military Uniforms
Liebig's Beef Extract "Military Uniforms" Italian issue, 1899, uploaded by user cigcardpix, Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/44841559@N03/7905469676/in/album-72157623485577978/)

---

### Trompettes de différents régiments de la cavalerie belge vers 1890, Uniforms of the Belgian Army 1880-90 by Luca Stefano Cristini

[image: Trompettes de différents régiments de la cavalerie belge vers 1890]
Source: [File:Uniformes armée belge.jpg uploaded by user Barbe-Noire, Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Uniformes_arm%C3%A9e_belge.jpg#filehistory)

---

Unfortunately I'm unable to add anymore links as a new user, but I will try to add the rest of my research in the comments!

Comment: The book I found and put in my answer matches the text in your question so precisely that I'm tempted to think this book cover might be why you thought it could be that? If there's more information you have on this from your own research, please edit it into the answer.

Comment: Looks like a chasseur a cheval (gidsen te paard) uniform.

Comment: @T.E.D. yes, that's why I thought so!  I also found a few images which I've lost now, if I find them again I will update the info. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Jos I will try and research this some more! I though it looked similar to chasseur a cheval also, and some Guide uniforms from the same period. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: A similar uniform is seen here: https://picclick.com/Military-Belgian-Army-Armee-Belge-%C3%89claireurs-dAvant-Garde-266151554766.html

larger image: https://www.picclickimg.com/g-4AAOSwAQVhgQYE/Military-Belgian-Army-Armee-Belge-Eclaireurs-dAvant-Garde.webp

Comment: some similar uniforms shown here https://www.abbl.be/category/uniforme-uniform/ particularly chasseurs a cheval 1914

Answer (score 3):

Turns out there's actually a book called "[Uniforms of the Belgian Army - 1880-90](https://soldiershop.com/shop/uniforms-of-the-belgian-army-late-xix-cent/)". The cover sure does look like your picture.

[image: Uniforms book cover]

Someone with access to the book might even be able to identify the unit, but it definitely does look like one of theirs.

Comment: I saw this book too and thought the same!